# Use target's scope as a condition of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, associations

I have models like

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :branch, :foreign_key => :branch_code, :primary_key => :branch_code,
    :conditions => proc{["? BETWEEN enabled_day AND expiration_day", Date.current]}
end

class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, :foreign_key => :branch_code, :primary_key => :branch_code

  scope :valid, lambda {where(["? BETWEEN enabled_day AND expiration_day", Date.current])}
end
```

employee belongs to an branch (simple), but branch has several records of same branch_code, and one that is "valid at this moment" should always be used.

(as you may guess, the project is porting of an old app and it succeeds the old schema)

Now, it does work, but I have to write exact same where condition twice (actually branch is associated to more tables, so 5 or 6 times).

wonder if I could use Branch's scope as condition of an association, or any other way to DRY things up?

Answer (score 0):

Would using has_many_through with default_scope work?

Something along the lines of:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_one :branch, :through => :assignments
end

class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :employees, :through => :assignments
end

class EmployeeAssignments < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :enabled_day, :expiration_day

  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :branch

  def self.default_scope
    where '? BETWEEN enabled_day AND expiration_day', Date.current
  end
end
```